# Using cbgreek with Unicode input

Tags: cbgreek

There is at least one package containing ancient Greek fonts written in
Metafont, `cbgreek`.  This is from its documentation:

```
% file test-cbgreek10pt.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[10pt]{type1ec}%
\begin{document}
Qa'ire!
Ἔρρωσο!
\end{document}
```

The output is Χαίρε! + gibberish.  Is it possible to use this package
entering the Greek with normal Greek Unicode letters instead of
transliterating?

Comment: The `type1ec` package is obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the `utf8` encoding in `inputenc`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[10pt]{type1ec}%
\begin{document}
  Qa'ire!
  Eρρωσο!
 \end{document}
```

Whose output is [image]